# People Lookup in SharePoint Online Form: Can I specify which users you can find and select?

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, people-picker, forms-library

I have a SharePoint Online form where a user can choose their name from the People lookup. I want each user to be able to choose their name only, not choose anyone else. But a Manager can choose whoever is under their OU in the AD.

Is that possible?

Thanks

**Ifti**

Comment: no, that is not possible, you will have to custom develop something for that

Comment: Thanks mate. I made a separate form where Manager can choose the employee's name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible. You have to create a new form for this type of scenarios for the Manager.